# Script to replace line that contains text

Tags: powershell, batch-file, replace, str-replace

I found another discussion on this, where there were numerous different options available but most of them didn't seem to work for myself or the original poster. I did however find an example that is confirmed working, however I am struggling with getting it to work and hoping for help.

I need to find a line that begins with "ServerName=" and replace this with my own line. I have used the example that was found and modified it, but I am getting errors when using it.

PowerShell Command:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content 'KFGame\Config\PCServer-KFGame.ini') | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '^ServerName.$', ('ServerName=Network BUF 12345 Normal')} | Set-Content  'KFGame\Config\PCServer-KFGame.ini'"
```

Error Message:

> ) was unexpected at this time

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, but as a first step you may want to remove most of the parentheses in that line. Only the outer parentheses around `Get-Content` are required. Also, the error might be caused by code prior to that line.

Comment: I updated the original post, I realized my first issue was running it from a bat without prepending "powershell -Command" to it. With the update though, it is now reporting 'Foreach-Object' is not recognized as internal/external command, program or batch file, why I suspect its still not actually running as powershell

Comment: The pipe is handled by CMD, not PowerShell. To prevent that you need to put the entire PowerShell code in quotes or (better yet) in a script that you run via the `-File` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run complex PowerShell statements from CMD you need to put them in quotes so that CMD just sees a string and doesn't try to handle special characters (like pipes):

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content 'C:\Host400.txt') | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '^workstationID.*$', (""WorkstationID=$computerName""} | Set-Content  'C:\Host400.txt'"
```

Note that you need to either escape or replace double quotes within the command string.

A better approach is to put the PowerShell statement(s) into a .ps1 script and run that via the `-File` parameter:

```
powershell -File "C:\path\to\your.ps1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this information helped a lot. My exact PS script seems to run without error now but isn't actually replacing the line. Can you check the original post and see if you see any problem with it at this point?

Comment: @BrettPowell There's an asterisk missing in your regular expression. Change `^ServerName.$`to `^ServerName.*$`.